# Is 'Borderlands: The Handsome Collection' a disc or digital (PS4)?

Tags: ps4, borderlands, borderlands-the-handsome-collection

So I saw that 'Borderlands: The Handsome Collection' for PS4 is on sale online. This includes the Borderlands 2 and the pre-sequel but my question is: will it be a digital game for Borderlands 2 and a physical game for the pre-sequel? Or will they both be physical games? Can I also play the game without updating it?

Comment: While you may have slow internet, and for what it's worth, the handsome collection will be free in June as apart of the monthly free games for PS+ members. If you saw the game in a local store and have PS+, you can save some money

Answer (score 1):

This can be both. I had the Handsome Collection on PS4 as  discs but it can also be purchased digitally on the PS4 store as well.

It comes as 2 discs in the case one for each.

Answer (score -3):

I do not know for this one in particular, but I often buy games on Amazon, and they always ship on discs.

I think it would be safe to say that if you are not buying from the PSN store, it's gonna be a disk. Logically, codes could be easily already used and then sent back, making a mess. So I would take the guess that every reseller will ship disks.

Just to make sure, contact the market place you are trying to buy from (you havent told us where you are buying it from, so we can't answer for sure).

Comment: I am buying it from Lazada.com. I din’t understand, does the physical copy of handsome jack collection have both games in the disk? Like you switch from borderlands 2 and the pre sequel? Or one of the game is a downloadable game?

Comment: @Bido262 both games are on the one disc - and a single launcher in the PS4 menu. When you launch the Handsome Collection, you then get a menu to choose between BL2 or the Pre-Sequel

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the andwer am looking for.